# Installing flutter bash_profile

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to install flutter
I need to create with the terminal a file named bash_profile 
I tried to create it but each time that I'm trying, I'm getting a bash_profile file with an extension: bash_profile.swo and bash_profile.swp instead of bash_profile.
How can I remove the 2  bash_profile.swo and bash_profile.swp?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `echo '' >> .bash_profile`.

You can also use the `touch` command to do it.

Remember that bash_profile file is a occulted file. you probably already have this file, try check it by running `ls -la`.

and you must to use a 'dot' before 'bash' >> `.bash`

Comment: thx! it work great. No I'm banned from stack. It's weird, I feel more sad than being banned from facebook ;-(